# Need to make str method return string instead of printing

Tags: python, string, return

I need the below str method written to return a string rather than print a string.

```
def __str__(self):
    """Returns the string representation of the student."""
    avg = sum(self.scores) / len(self.scores)
    print("Name: " + str(self.name))
    print("Score 1: " + str(self.scores[0]))
    print("Score 2: " + str(self.scores[1]))
    print("Score 3: " + str(self.scores[2]))
    print("High: " + str(int(max(self.scores))))
    print("Average: %.2f\n" % avg)
```

Comment: You should try by replacing multiple print, by return (str1 +'\n' +str2+'\n' +...) ... try and tell us if you managed to do it.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is convert all those print statements into one string, while maintaining the newlines that you already have.

Something like this should work in place of **str**

```py
def __str__(self):
        avg = sum(self.scores) / len(self.scores)
        s = ""
        s += "Name: " + str(self.name) + "\n"
        s += "Score 1: " + str(self.scores[0]) + "\n"
        s += "Score 2: " + str(self.scores[1]) + "\n"
        s += "Score 3: " + str(self.scores[2]) + "\n"
        s += "High: " + str(int(max(self.scores))) + "\n"
        s += "Average: %.2f\n" % avg + "\n"
        return s
```

Comment: Since this is now returning a string, you're going to need to print the string after, so in 

for s in students:
        print(s.__str__())